# How to protect password sending through httpclient method in java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

From `SCAVA` security scan tool it is reported that some of my code lines are subject to vulnerability.
The vulnerability classification is :

#### `Insufficient_Sensitive_Transport_Layer`

The vulnerable code contains
`httpclient.addHeader()` method sending password to login a `server/api`.
Application is in java langauge.

From google, I got to know that we can add some encryption method to avoid this vulnerability.

```
HttpGet getMethod = null;
getMethod = new HttpGet("http/https url to connect");
getMethod.addHeader(USERNAME,PASSWORD); // Vulnerability reported in
//this line as it is sending the password without any protection.
```

How can i prevent this vulnerability and pass the password in a secure way through some encryption method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two options: If the server accepts encrypted passwords, use that encryption method. Otherwise, use SSL.

Comment: some times these are reported as false positive, some times they are not.  The password is not hard coded? Is there an option for OAuth?

Comment: @PaulBastide The password is not hardcoded.

Comment: @ManojVadehra    the below lines are correct or not ?as in google they encrypted like this                                         getMethod.addHeader(USERNAME,
   DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary((PASSWORD).getBytes()));

Comment: That's not really encrypted.

Comment: @Sudharshjasmine Base64 is _encoding_ not _encryption_.

Comment: This is hardly any _less_ secure than standard HTTP BASIC auth scheme

Answer (score 1):

Enable [Transport Layer Security (TLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) each time you have to send credentials as plain text. If you have correctly configured `https://` with latest secure version of TLS the communication will be secure.

Moreover, there are situations where sending plain text credentials can't be avoided e.g. user login process. Automatic scanning tools might not be smart enough to distinguish valid use cases and raise a false-positive.